# eclipse/java -- java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ndbclient in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, jnienv

This seems to be a very simple problem and I'm hoping for a simple answer. I've read many posts on this but haven't found a solution.

Here's a simple program:

```
package org.foo.test.LoadLibTest;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException 
    {   
        System.loadLibrary("ndbclient");
    }
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ndbclient in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1764)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
    at org.paiego.test.LoadLibTest.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I've modified the java.library.path by using the following argument. And this path is indeed valid and contains the library.

```
-Djava.library.path=/Users/foo/projects/hl/jpa_test/my-app/lib/
```

and the lib directory contains:

```
libndbclient.so
```

I'm using a 64-bit OS:

```
Darwin paiego.local 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Yet a 32 bit version of Eclipse:

```
-arch
x86
```

And the library I'm attempting to load is from 64 bit installation of MySQL Cluster 5.6

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I may be just really stupid today but aren't .so files for C/C++ not java?

Comment: can you verify that the native is at the location you pointed it to?

Comment: @Excellent : Ultimately I'm trying to load a library and use JNI. This is required for MySQL cluster clients (done for efficiency). For this post, I tried to create as simple example as possible.

Comment: @Mark: You are correct. But I still have my original issue with trying to use *java.library.path*, and a simple call to loadLibrary(). As you can see I edited the original post.

Comment: I havent personally used the library path, typically I deploy my natives along side the application (like a JFX bundle or something). Are you sure you cant use the load(String FileName) method, or perhaps this: System.loadLibrary(mapLibraryName("libndbclient.so")); 
Unsatisfied link errors are tough, and Reimeus is probably right... the natives need to be the same target CPU build as the code you are running.

Comment: Sorry, too late to edit the comment, thats System.mapLibraryName(String)

Answer (score 2):

You need a 64-bit version of Java to match the 64-bit version of your shared library.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will do this. But before I do would you please re-visit the question, which has just been edited by me, and see if *this* issue can also be caused by a mix of 32-bit/64-bit?

Comment: Yes indeed it can. This is actually a common issue. I've seen this with other libraries. The error message is the same as though the library does not exist :)

Comment: @Reimeus, what role does the eclipse build version play in this reimeus? I would think that the only thing that matters is that the natives are the correct build for the libraries which actually make the native calls, so the java 64 bit version, a 64 bit version of the library, and a 64 bit build of the natives all seem appropriate, but Eclipse version doesn't fit.

Comment: @MarkW Yes, as long as you can load Java 64 bit from 32 bit Eclipse there is no problem. (Some libraries have associated native plugins though - that's why I suggested 64 bit Eclipse also)